# ImageMagick.NET PDF to JPG conversion - insufficient memory

Tags: c#, pdf, imagemagick, jpeg, magick.net

I'm using ImageMagick.NET to convert PDFs to JPGs.  Here's my code:

```
    MagickReadSettings settings = new MagickReadSettings();
    settings.Density = new MagickGeometry(300, 300);

    using (MagickImageCollection images = new MagickImageCollection())
    {
        images.Read(pdfFilePathString, settings);

        MagickImage image = images.AppendVertically();
        image.Format = MagickFormat.Jpg;
        //image.Quality = 70; 
        //if (image.Width > 1024)
        //{
        //    int heightRatio = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round((decimal)(image.Height / (image.Width / 1024)), 0));
        //    image.Resize(1024, heightRatio);
        //}
        image.Write(tempFilePathString);               
        image.Dispose();
    }
```

The problem is, I keep getting insufficient memory exceptions, which occur on the image.Write().  It is obviously due to file size, as a small pdf will work, but not a multi page pdf.  The particular file I'm trying to get it to run through is a 12 page text pdf.  I can get it to work if I sent the density low, for example (100, 100) works, but the quality is terrible.

The commented out lines were some other solutions I was trying to implement, but it keeps running for a long time (several minutes) without end (at least as far as my patience is concerned) with those enabled.  One of those is to reduce quality, and the other to reduce image size.  The pdfs always come out very large, much larger than necessary.

If I could reduce image size and/or quality before the file is written, that would be great.  Or at least I need to be able to be able to produce an image in a quality that is decent enough without having memory issues.  It doesn't seem like it should be having memory issues here as its not as if the file size is ginormous, although it probably still is bigger than desired for an image.  The 12 page pdf when I could get it to render came in at around 6-7 megs.

I'm using 32-bit ImageMagick - I wonder if 64-bit would solve the issue, but there have been issues trying to get that version to run on a local environment - which is another issue entirely.

Anybody have any thoughts on anything else I can try?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to use Ghostscript.NET to convert PDF to Jpg? Take a look here: http://ghostscriptnet.codeplex.com

Comment: Can you add a link to your pdf? Feel free to also start a topic here: https://magick.codeplex.com/discussions.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer or possible solution to this issue? I'm having similar issues in which I have multiple .tiff files and trying to convert to one.pdf with some documents having well over 450 images.  At around 2MB though, I start getting output buffer memory errors.

Comment: Never got a solution to this.  ImageMagick was ultimately removed from the project I was working on at the time.